Is there a way to upgrade from unsupported 18.04 (64 bit)?
Again, is there a way to upgrade from 18.04 64 bit Bionic Beaver version that is now unsupported to a version that is supported?
If not, is there at least a way for me to save bookmarks from Firefox that is also now unsupported and transfer to a supported version? Can I find them somewhere on the hard drive by searching with terminal? Does Firefox retain them in some archive? I need to try to salvage what I can from the hard drive before installing a supported version and losing all personal data.
Thanks in advance for your thoughts and suggestions! ~ Emily

Did you look at the docs?  for example https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades   Do note 18.04 is EOL or EOSS depending on architecture, which you didn't provide, and this can influence what is required to be done  (FYI:  64-bit says nothing as there are many - arm64, amd64, ppc64el, riscv64 etc are all 64-bit)

If you're using a 64-bit architecture that is still in ESM support; you can release-upgrade normally without any change; it's only slightly more complex if using an architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) that is now EOL as archives have moved thus EOLUpgrades extra steps may be required (or if using i386 or 32-bit x86 there is no upgrade path!)

FYI:  When you release-upgrade the system will just keep your browser (firefox) settings, and even when/if the deb package is replaced by snap, the prior settings are imported into the newly installed snap package. You've left your upgrade well outside of support ; so all QA (Quality Assurance) testing on that upgrade path was done long ago & things may have changed; but backup your files normally anyway in case you have problems.

for the bookmarks in FF your best option is to create a Firefox account which, when you log in to your new version, will allow you to import them very easily.to any new device you select.

Firefox bookmarks

If you want to save only the firefox data ~/.mozilla/firefox/ might be a starting point.
Taking a complete backup of the homefolder(s) concerned might be a good idea, in the hidden folders starting with "." like .mozilla a lot is stored that is automatically accessed by the application which created it
Alternatively, open a firefox account and sign in. It will sync all your bookmarks, and all bookmarks will be restored when you sign in to another device/new installation.

the homefolder(s) and the DOT files and folders - these are revealed by e.g. ls -A in terminal or CTRL+H in Nautilus (gnome "Files").
